# Can I take motion sickness pills abroad without a doctor's note?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, health, airport-security, drugs

I'm planning on going around Europe, Asia and Canada and I tend to have really bad travel sickness. I take the brand Kwells. The tablets really help.

I buy them at my local pharmacy. As the question says, am I allowed to take them with me through security and onto the plane without needing a doctor's note?

It would really help if anyone takes motion sickness tablets abroad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's also known as Scopolamine (particularly in the US).

Comment: Typically there is not a problem with taking your medication *onto* the plane (so the [tag:airport-security] tag isn't really the issue).  The question is whether the customs agents in the destination country will let you bring it into the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every country has their own categorization of medicines which indicates which ones are allowed to be taken without any documentation, which need a prescription, ones that need more documentation and those that are completely banned.

For motion sickness pills, they are *usually* allowed. Pretty much any medication that is available over-the-counter at your destination country, will be allowed in.

In Canada, it is easy to purchase Gravol and I have taken those pills with me to easily over 40 different countries without ever having in issue. They have a very mild effect though and so in Brazil I switched to Meclizine Chlorhydrate. The difference is night and day. Although these are not available in Canada, I have taken them there, to the US, to Europe (Portugal & The Czech Republic), to the middle-East, Africa and Asia (11 countries in all). Again, I never had any problems taking these with me to any of these countries.

EDIT: Someone in the comments indicated that Kwells is Scopolamine. This is a highly controlled substance . In Canada and the US, it is only available with a prescription. You will need a doctor to write you a letter explaining that you need this medicine. That will not guarantee it will be allowed in though. I  had a similar letter written for another medication but whether it is recognized at any of your destinations is up to them. Generally, if you are carrying a small enough quantity for personal use, theses things do not get noticed.

Comment: It's available in the US, but requires a prescription.

Comment: The term "[controlled substance](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/)" has a specific legal meaning in US law and as far as I can tell, scopolamine isn't one.  It does appear to require a prescription, though.

Answer (score 4):

It might depend on what exactly the ingredients are, and especially which country you are going to. You will not have issues in the US.

In the USA, a lot of medication can be bought over the counter that need prescriptions in other countries, or that are illegal/controlled substances.

However, for a limited amount and with the original packaging - there should be little issues anywhere; it is obvious that you are not smuggling drugs, but only have a personal supply, and equally obvious that they are freely sold in the US. I wouldn’t worry at all.

To be absolute sure, you would have to compare the ingredient list with the target country’s legislation.

Comment: I would also note that even a doctor's note won't necessarily help when abroad - e.g. Australia only recognizes prescriptions from Australian-registered doctors.

Comment: Scopolamine is prescription-only in the US.  I wouldn't say it is "freely sold".  There are other motion sickness medications that are over-the-counter, however, so OP could consider trying one of those instead.